# matching unicode char in css selectors

Tags: css, unicode, css-selectors

Strange question but I would like to match unicode characters in a selector attribute in css

I think an example is worth a thousand words:

In the following example, the last 4 selectors do not work

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}


/* writing the unicode char is of
course working, but I don't want to past complexe
unicode char in my css */

[value="a"] {
  background-color: pink;
}


/* html notation */

[value="&#97;"],

/* unicode notation */

[value="U+F52A"],

/* css content notation */

[value="\97"],

/* js notation */

[value="\u97"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input value="&#97;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS escapes](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes) values using a backslash and hex value of the unicode point value.

For instance, for `a` ([dec = 97, hex = `0x61`](https://unicodelookup.com/)), you can use `\61` or `\000061`:

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}


/* using hex value https://unicodelookup.com/ */
[value="\61"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input value="&#97;">
```